# The package at "node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "util"

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am getting below error when I am trying to run the react-native app on an android phone

Failed building JavaScript bundle.
The package at "node_modules\uuidv4\build\lib\uuidv4.js" attempted
to import the Node standard library module "util".
It failed because the native React runtime does not include the
Node standard library. Read more at
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries

But it is working on the web(web browser)....help me to fix this error

Answer (score 1):

Try on your terminal and restart your VS Code or text editor

```
npm install util
```